# completion handler can not dismiss the popAlertController

Tags: swift, xcode, uialertcontroller, http-get, completion

I have a view controller with a single textView which I get a string from server and set on it.

I call a http-get service in **viewDidAppear** and I need to show a popUp alert for waiting user till get the string

I do all but I can not dismiss the popalert and app stacks in loading alert

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        fetchAndPrintEachPerson()

        networkReachablity()

        popUpLoading() // start showing loading pop alert

        getPerson ()

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        style()
        giftTextFiled.isEnabled = false



    }

    func popUpLoading(){

        popUpAlert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "wait ...", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

        popUpAlert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
        present(popUpAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

    func getPerson(){

        guard let url=URL(string: "\(address)person/code") else {return}

        print(url)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            if let res=response {

                //print(res)
            }
            do {

                if let dataContent=data {

                    let con = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataContent, options: []) as? AnyObject
                    let data = con??["data"] as? AnyObject
                    let code = data?["code"] as? String
                    print(code)
                    // self.popUpAlert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                     DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    //self.giftTextFiled.text=code!
                    self.giftTextFiled.isEnabled = true
                self.popUpAlert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

                     })
                    //})
                }else {
                    let snack=snackBarAlert()
                    snack.alert(title: "error", color: UIColor.red)
                    self.popUpAlert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }catch let err{
                print(err)
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.popUpAlert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

})
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

update first post.

Comment: Do you have an error message in console? Because that's related to UI, so it should be don in main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting that inside view DidLoad & check whether your getting a response from the server other wise it will fall through else block and keep showing the pop up

Comment: I have handle it both condition but some time not dismissing pop up

Answer (score 0):

`URLSession.shared.dataTask` completion closure is called on non-main thread, which may produce unexpected results for UI. Dispatch your UI code to main thread.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Your UI related code
    }
}.resume()
```

Comment: I have comment it DispatchQueue inside my code it means I have test it before. some time not dismissing pop up and keep showing it.

Comment: In your code `dismiss` is not called inside the dispatch block. I can only see you're setting the `giftTextFiled`. You are also calling `dismiss` in the else clause which is non-main thread. And your `getPerson ` completion is called on non-main thread.